# Cast from object to int loses precision C++

Tags: c++, casting

In my TimeCode.h I have following :

```
inline TimeCode::operator int() const;
```

Which should be able to execute whenever I cast TimeCode object to int.

But when I do something like :

```
(int) firstTimeCode > (int) scndTimeCode
```

The compiler throws the following error at me :

```
cast from 'TimeCode*' to 'int' loses precision [-fpermissive]
```

Does anyone know what is the problem and how it can be fixed ? Thank you very much in advance !

Comment: You're casting a pointer address to an `int`, not a `TimeCode`.

Comment: You compare the pointer, overload the operator ```<``` or ```>```.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at the error message - it's telling you that you're converting `TimeCode*` to `int` - that is, at least one of your operands is a *pointer* to a `TimeCode`, not an actual `TimeCode`. So you need to dereference that pointer first to invoke your operator correctly.